# Blender: animate material or alpha of linked object

Tags: animation, materials, keyframes, geometry-nodes

I have linked an object (Blender 3.1) and I'd like to make it gradually appear. I saw that one can do that using keyframes on alpha in the material. Unfortunately, I can't change the alpha of this material as all properties are grayed out:

[image]

Is there a solution to my problem that does not overwrite completely the material? Also, my object is created using a Geometry Node, so it means that I needed to manually apply the material inside the Geometry Node (no idea if there is a better solution):

[image]

**EDIT**

I would like to avoid to duplicate or (worse) to create a new material from scratch, as I won't get updates when the original material is changed.

I already have a library override on the object, and I also tried to add a library override to the material, but I can't find how to do:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to do a [library override](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/linked_libraries/library_overrides.html) on either the object or the material from the outliner?

Comment: @L0Lock I have one on the object, but I can't find how to apply it to the material

Comment: Hi :). Or you can connect *Object info node > Color* the material's Alpha, and control it that way :)

Comment: @JachymMichal you mean after creating a new shape? The problem is that it won't update if the underlying material changes.

Comment: Unfortunately material overrides don't really work as of right now. You'll have to create a local copy I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *Object Info* node in the linked material

1. Add *Object Info > Color* to drive transparency in the linked material
2. Link Object to another scene
3. Adjust transparency through *Viewport Display > Color*

<sup>Linked instance</sup>
[image]

<sup>Linked material setup</sup>
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works nicely and is relatively quick to setup, but it lacks a bit of configurability (you can use at most 4 sliders or one color). I found a solution exploiting custom properties and drivers.

Answer (score 1):

The proposition of Jachym is fairly nice, but I found it to be not configurable enough for more complex setup (the advantage is that it is really quick to setup, but sadly I can't have more than 4 floats to configure my whole object…). Instead, I found out that I could use object properties + drivers (drivers allow you to bind any property/computed value to any slider). This works even when the material is embedded inside a Geometry node (which is not the case of the solution based on duplicating the material or using group node). The solution is first to create some properties for your object:

[image]

Then to configure it (you can choose any name/type inluding colors/min/max you like), notably to allow library overrides:

[image]

[image]

The new properties appear also in the object properties (type N in the viewport):

[image]

Note that you can also configure a color (with or without an alpha channel), like this:

[image]

[image]

Then, copy the name of your custom property by **right** clicking on it and selecting "Copy Data Path":

[image]

Then, in your Shader Editor, **right** click on the slider you would like to change (here the alpha parameter), and add a driver (it basically binds any value/property to a slider):

[image]

then, in the list, choose your object, and paste the previously copied data path. Update `var+1` to `var`:

[image]

Now, you can change your alpha directly from your object property, and link it (link the whole collection) and use libraries override on it as before.

Comment: Hey :) . Thanks for sharing your solution in detail. I'll probably use it in some future projects ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your material is linked, and must be un-linked to be edited. Click on the paperclip icon next to the material name "Virus" to create a local copy

Comment: I can't click on the paperclip as it's grey (no idea why, I also reported this before without success). The problem also of this is that if the material changes it won't be synced into account in my new copy.